# Can i clear only the AEM level SAML Assertion and not the IDP SAML session.?

Tags: aem, saml-2.0

i have a use case requirement where i required to clear only the AEM related SAML Assertion and not the IDP level SAML session. is there any OOB way to achieve it. I have tried /system/sling/logout.html which shows only "session_timeout" output, but when i access any page of AEM in the same browser i can see the SAML authenticated user is still logged in.

Comment: Have you unchecked the `handleLogout` checkbox in the SAML handler config ?

Comment: Yes, i have unchecked the handleLogout and tested, then AEM is just clearing the AEM logged in cookie not the SAML Assertion.

Comment: What do you mean by clearing the assertion ?